# parameter thread in vb

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

First of all, i don't have a good understanding about thread in vb, i tried to get info about it, but i'm still confused about how its work, addressof, the correct implementation and so on. I want to ask about how to create a new thread with parameter so i pass a value from the main thread. 
I try to do a loop and each loop create a new thread and do ping. Below is my code:

```
For i = 10 To 50
    Dim worker As New Thread(New ThreadStart(Function()
                                                 My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.1." & i)
                                                 Console.WriteLine("192.168.1." & i)
                                             End Function))
    worker.Start()
Next
```

I realize this is wrong because the result will loop and ping the last value of variable i. So i want to ask about the correct suggestion about it. I will really appreciate if you add a simple explanation for me just to get a better understanding about thread.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. However, since you are using the same variable for all your created threads. So when your thread starts it more or less contains a pointer to i rather than the value of i. Which means that as your loop progress the value of i change. So when your threads actually start working the loop has completed and the value of i has changed to 51.

To resolve this you have to create a new integer inside the loop. So that the supplied object is unique for every loop. Like so:

```
Dim x as Integer = i
```

Then supply x instead of i to the Thread and you are all set.

Here is some reading on the topic: 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/closures-in-vb-part-5-looping/

Comment: That line really solved this. I tested it 3 times, and result was good. But just a little curious about the result (please consider that this is not a next question). The threads that created is not really in sequence order. Like : Ping 192.168.1.10
Ping 192.168.1.11
Ping 192.168.1.13
Ping 192.168.1.12
Ping 192.168.1.15
Ping 192.168.1.14
Ping 192.168.1.20. But however the result is correct. no ip skipped. Thank you so much @WozzeC

Comment: You are running threads, so the thread prints the output as soon as it can. This means that as soon as the Ping is completed it prints. So if .10 takes 20ms to ping and .11 takes 15ms to ping, then .11 will print before .10. If you want to have them in order you should look at the other answer. @tukangjam. Also, dont forget to mark answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/) as a better alternative.

**Example**

Make sure you make the caller async method by using the `async` keyword:

```vb
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim ip As String = $"192.168.1.{i}"

        Await Task.Run(Sub() Pinger(ip))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Pinger(ip As String)
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(ip) Then
        Console.WriteLine($"{ip} is alive.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine($"{ip} is dead.")
    End If
End Sub
```

The output:

```
192.168.1.1 is alive.
192.168.1.2 is dead.
192.168.1.3 is dead.
192.168.1.4 is dead.
192.168.1.5 is alive.
```

Why do you get an ordered sequence? I quote:

> The method usually includes at least one await expression, which marks
>   a point where the method can't continue until the awaited asynchronous
>   operation is complete.

Please refer to the given link above for more useful details.

Comment: Thank  you @JQSOFT for your answer and explanation. This is also a good solution for another part of my script

Comment: While `Task`-based work can be pushed onto background threads and `Await`ed, `Async` and `Await` are really somewhat orthogonal to threading.  Not everything that gets `Await`ed will end up on a thread.  I think it would be more appropriate in this case to focus on the `Task`-oriented part.  I'd highly recommend reading Stephen Cleary's various blog posts on the subject.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for your valuable comment. It will be nice if you could translate that in a post using the simple example here. I know we have an accepted answer,  however, having different solutions/opinions/corrections  will make this post more useful and not to mention, we are here to learn as well.

Comment: @JQSOFT Will do.